# How to show table data in separate page in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

This is my **dashboard.html**  where all the user data will display from **controller** file. Now what I want is that when I click the button of each user it will display the information of user in a separate page.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script src="newcontroller.js"></script>
        <script src="controller.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylingpage.css">

</head>
<body ng-app="myModule">
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
<h2 align="center">Welcome</h2>
<table width="20%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>UserName</th>
            <th>Password</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="employee in employees">
                <td>{{employee.id}}</td>
                <td>{{employee.name}}</td>
                <td>{{employee.password}}</td>
                <td><button type="button" ng-click="view()">View</button></td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
</table>
</div>  
</body>
</html>
```

When I click the View button it will display that person info in separate page. How can I do it? Please help. Thanks in advance.

This is my **controller.js file**:

```
var app=angular.module('mainApp',['ngRoute']);
app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
    .when('/',{
        templateUrl:'login.html'
    })
    .when('/newdashboard',{
        resolve:{
            "check":function($location,$rootScope){
                if(!$rootScope.loggedIn){
                    $location.path('/');
                }

            }
        },
            templateUrl:'newdashboard.html'

    })
    .when('/userdetails',{

        templateUrl:'userdetails.html'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo:'/'
    });
});
app.controller('loginCtrl',function($scope,$location,$rootScope){
    $scope.submit=function(){

        if($scope.username=='admin' && $scope.password =='admin'){
            $rootScope.loggedIn=true;
            $location.path('/newdashboard');
        }else{
            alert('wrong Username or password. Try Again');
        }
    };
});

app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
            $scope.employees=[
               {id:"101",name:"User 1",password:"User1@123"},
               {id:"102",name:"User 2",password:"User2@123"},
               {id:"103",name:"User 3",password:"User3@123"},
               {id:"104",name:"User 4",password:"User4@123"},
               {id:"105",name:"User 5",password:"User5@123"},
               {id:"106",name:"User 6",password:"User6@123"}
             ];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i believe there's more than enough ways to do this just search **"passing objects between controllers angularjs"** [google](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=passing+objects+between+controllers+angularjs&*) can get you more than enough results..
 it's either done by passing the object in URL, a service ,or using local storage.
common things are

- you'll need a controller for the details page
- you'll probably need to pass the `employee` object in the `view()` function --> `view(employee)`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it, in following way.

Step 1 - Update your HTML to pass, employee Id as parameter in "view" method

```
<td><button type="button" ng-click="view(employee.id)">View</button></td>
```

Step 2 - Update routing state to send the ID as parameter for detail page.

```
.when('/userdetails/:id',{
   templateUrl:'userdetails.html'
})
```

Step 3 - Write the "view" function to change state from listing page to detail page. Add it in your "myCtrl" method

```
 $scope.view= function(userId) {
          $location.path('/userdetails/').search({id: userId});
 }
```

Step 4 - To get parameter on detail page(In controller method) in following way.

```
var urlParams = $location.search();
urlParams.id will return Empolyee Id
```

So now you have selected employee Id on detail page controller, so you can bind the details of that employee to view.

Comment: var urlParams = $location.search();
urlParams.id where to define these two line.